# ngAnimate not working inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, css, ng-animate

I'm triying to add an nganimation for my main loader page with no luck :(. This is how I'm trying to achieve this. Im using a directive:

```
<html>
...
<loader-gui></loader-gui>
</html>
```

which has this code inside:

```
<div class="loader-gui" loader>
    <img src="img/loader.gif"/> 
</div>
```

with this directive:

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', [])

.directive('loaderGui', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/loader-gui.html'
    }
})

.directive('loader', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.isLoading = function () {
                return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
            };
            $scope.$watch($scope.isLoading, function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    element.removeClass('ng-hide');
                } else {
                    element.addClass('ng-hide');
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

So, this is working perfect, after load all the resources and http requests my `loader-gui` dissapears. But I want to make it more fancy using nganimate to make a fadeout effect, simple.

I've added the library, the module into my app with out any errors and my custom CSS.

**myapp.css**

```
.ng-hide {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
}
```

**myapp.js**

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngAnimate', 'myapp.directives']);
```

But it's not working, it's just dissapear without any effect. Am I missing something? Any advice? I've read samples with methods fired up trough a $scope but not using a directive.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't included ngAnimate as a dependency in your main module, you certainly would want to do so here.

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', ['ngAnimate'])
```

Comment: thanks!, I've add the dependency in my main app: angular.module('myapp', ['ngAnimate']);

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the best practice to make animation for `ngHide` and some other directives is by handling the "transition" classes which automatically added and removed during transition by the `ngAnimate`. For `ngHide` and `ngShow` the transition classes is named `.ng-hide-add` and `.ng-hide-remove`.

On the official angular documentation for `ngHide` they give good example to playing with those 2 classes. Please check this out for more detail example how to do that : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide#example . Please pay attention at the `animate-hide` which they add to the element that need to be animate. And also the CSS file which contain detail of class styling for the animation.